# which language is better to convert excel to xml

Tags: java, vb.net, excel, vba

i need to write a script to arrange data in excel and convert into xml automaticlly
which language is more suitable, java or VBA macro? or anything else?
but VB looks a little ..confused
anybody do this kind of programming before, give me some suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

If you use Java, your can use Apache POI to read Excel files, and use JAXB to generate XML files.

Apache POI: http://poi.apache.org/

JAXB: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's not a question of the language, but a question of an appropriate library. Possibly there are good libraries to manipulate excel in VB as they originate from the same company. In java, however, you'll find some libraries which make manipulating and exporting excel. One of the libraries in java is:

http://poi.apache.org/